# Local/self hosted facial recognition software similar to PimEyes

Tags: facial-recognition

I have tens of thousands of photos in a directory on my computer. I'm looking for facial recognition software similar to PimEyes.

Requirements:

- I want be able to input or upload a face (jpg, png, etc), and in return get all the photos that contain that face. I am not looking for a list of all faces found in the photos, only faces that match the single given face.
- Must have the same accuracy as PimEyes or better.
- It should run on Windows, a gui would be nice but command line would be ok too.
- Be able to handle 50k+ photos.
- Runs locally, without the need to upload the photos online.
- Doesn't need all the features of PimEyes, only need the option to be able to open file location or something like that.

My budget is $30/mo or even better if it's free.